# Other ways of disabling default maven plugins as via phase none?

Tags: maven, dependabot

For some of my projects I don't need the default maven plugins, as for an example I use there no or other compilers. Disabling these plugins saves execution time and build output in this case.

For the moment the only way to disable default maven plugins I found is the following:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I have enabled dependabot on my code, which informs me now everytime, when there is a new version of the plugin, despite I don't use it.

If I delete the version, then maven gives warnings like the following:
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing.

So my question is: Are there other ways of disabling the standard maven plugins which does not need the pluging version number and does not generate such maven warnings?

Kind regards
Torsten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't build a JAR or WAR, you can set `<packaging>pom</packaging>` in the POM file, which leads to a minimum number of default plugins.

Default plugins are set by the lifecycle, and the lifecycle is determined by the packaging. You can even define your own packaging `<packaging>kleiber</packaging>` with your own lifecycle and default plugins.

Comment: <packaging>pom</packaging> seems the right solution to me, I use the same lifecycle now, but with non standard plugins. Thanks a lot!